# How do I have a winform field automatically submit the form after swiping a credit card?

Tags: winforms, submit, credit-card

In a cash register program I am creating, I want to the form to automatically submit after the credit card is swiped. How is this done? Do all credit cards have the same number of characters stored in the magnetic stripe?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you swiped the credit card and get the max length of the Pin Number of credit card. and in the `TextBox` `TextChanged Event`

```
if (textBox.Length == pinNumberLength)
{
   submitButton.PerformClick()//or logic here
}
```